# How to prevent update a pretrained model if a model is optimized with backpropagation in Pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, optimization, backpropagation

I use Pytorch exclusively to develop my model, and these are components in my model and how it works:

- A generator
- An encoder: a pretrained, and should not updated.
- A loss function.
  Input is passed to the encoder to generate X, X is then passed to generator to generated a value Y. Y is passed to the encoder to get Z. The loss function computes error between Z and X. I detached X to prevent update the encoder. But I cannot detach Z, otherwise, the generator cannot be updated. But I also realize if Z is not detach then the encoder is also updated.
  In the case, how can I prevent the encoder being updated, and still allow the generator get feedback from the loss?

Comment: Hi @Jesse, welcome to the site. From your description, it is not clear how your architecture is. Can you provide more information or add a link to a reference that describes it in detail? Also, what exactly are X, Y and Z? And what does "computes error between Z and the Z and X" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .requires_grad = False on your model components, and then train as normal.

You can look at this post for that information.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748138/pytorch-how-to-set-requires-grad-false

Since you only want to freeze encoder layers, is there some substring(s) in the dictionary key that can be used to identify encoder weights? If so, you can just add a conditional around the statement that sets .requires_grad = False.